# Piwik accepts data from _every_ domain?

Tags: dns, matomo

I currently use Piwik 1.12. During Deployment the code passes 3 differents Domains till its deployd finally on live server:

```
local: myapp.local
dev: myapp.mycompany.com
live: myapp.customer.com
```

Piwik snippet is included in every of those 3 stages. I wonder why piwik accepts push events from *all* those 3 different domains, although live domain is entered as alias URL in piwik only.

Am i right that setting "setTrackerUrl" and "setSiteId" are sufficient for piwik to acceppt events? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Piwik will accept events from all domains. Only the Site id is used.